# Can't access object of class nil Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, embedded-ruby

I get this errormsg from doing tests in Rails 4

```
Error:
ArticlesControllerTest#test_x:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `state' for nil:NilClass
```

The error occurs at this line in the view:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <div id="article-container">
      <div id="article-content">
        <ul>
          <li> <b>Status:</b> <%= article.status_id %></li>
          <li> <b>State:</b> <%= article.state.state %></li
```

>

The model looks like this for article

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book, primary_key: :ISBN, foreign_key: :ISBN
  has_one :state, primary_key: :states_id, foreign_key: "id"
  has_one :status, primary_key: :status_id, foreign_key: "id"

  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses

  validates :ISBN, presence: true
  validates :states_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :price, presence: true
  validates :status_id, presence: true
```

This is the article and states table in schema

**Article table:**

```
  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "ISBN"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.integer  "status_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "states_id"
    t.index ["states_id"], name: "index_articles_on_states_id"
  end
```

**State table:**

```
  create_table "states", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "state"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

The problem is running this test (showing file from top until the test in question):

```
require 'test_helper'

class ArticlesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  setup do
    @article_normal = articles(:normal_article)
    @article_admin = articles(:admin_article)
    @normal_user = users(:normal_user)
    @admin_user = users(:admin_user)

    @normal_user.id = @article_normal.user_id
    @admin_user.id = @article_admin.user_id
  end
  test "test x" do
    get articles_url
    assert_response :success
  end
```

The test provides the error message, while in localhost it works.

**EDIT**
The test database is populated with fixtures.

**Article fixtures**

```
normal_article:
  ISBN: 9788252179675
  user_id: 1
  price: 500
  states_id: 1
  status_id: 1


admin_article:
  ISBN: 9788252179675
  user_id: 2
  price: 400
  states_id: 1
  status_id: 1
```

The controller method from article_controller:

```
# GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
    @courses = Course.all
    @states = State.all
    if params[:search]
      @articles = Article.search(params[:search])
    else
      @articles = Article.all
    end
  end
```

Comment: Are you populating data in Article Model in your test database before the test is running ?

Comment: Articles are populated, because i've tested that. The problem lies in accessing the states table, maybe there's something with the relationships i've missed. I can access 'article.states_id' and 'article.state', but no 'article.state.state', according to the test that is. It works when viewing in localhost

Comment: Done most of that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `article` fixtures do not reference the `state` fixtures correctly.

Instead of referencing a `state` by a fixed `id` (you use: `state_id: 1` in your fixture), give each `state` in your state fixtures a proper name and use that name like this: `state: valid_state`

---

Quote from the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#yaml) about how to work with associations in fixtures:

> If you are working with associations, you can simply define a reference node between two different fixtures. Here's an example with a `belongs_to`/`has_many` association:
>
> ```
> # In fixtures/categories.yml
> about:
>  name: About
>
> # In fixtures/articles.yml
> first:
>   title: Welcome to Rails!
>   body: Hello world!
>   category: about
> ```
>
> Notice the `category` key of the `first` article found in `fixtures/articles.yml` has a value of `about`. This tells Rails to load the category about found in `fixtures/categories.yml`.
>
> *For associations to reference one another by name, you can use the fixture name instead of specifying the id: attribute on the associated fixtures. Rails will auto assign a primary key to be consistent between runs. [...]*